# Flutter widget random position generator

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to get this UI:

[image: Ui example]

The goal is to generate widgets around a central point. (With random size and position)

I looked into the package flutter_staggered_grid_view package, but couldn't find a scalable solution. One that's sufficient for 2 widgets, but also for 50 widgets.

Are there ways to achieve this UI?

Thanks

Comment: I would like code for it. I want to ask, would you mind if they are overlapping?

Comment: @PrathamSarankar it would be better if they don’t overlap.

Comment: @PrathamSarankar do you have a solution in mind. Would be extremely helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Hey! I have got an idea. This can be achieved by pure mathematics. The equations of lines, angles, circles and areas. I am trying them. How much time have you got? Is it urgent? I need a day or two.

Comment: @PrathamSarankar thank you very much! You are amazing :) It’s a deadline of a week, so not that urgent. I would like to think with you, is it possible to stay in touch via messenger? You can contact me via messenger: Karel Debedts